# Is there a Spanish equivalent for "a trickle or a torrent"?

Tags: modismos

Is there an equivalent Spanish idiom to the effect of something being "either a trickle or a torrent"? My (feeble) attempt to translate it to Spanish would be:

> Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle, siempre es o [un goteo|un chorrito] o [un torrente|una inundación].

... but if there were something more idiomatic/recognisable to a native speaker, that would be even better.

Comment: I can't think of any expressions like that right now, but what comes to the top of my head is "no tener término medio" like in "Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle,**no tengo término medio**: o hablo un montón o no digo prácticamente nada".

Comment: Okay thanks Diego! I'll wait a while to see if there's any other suggestions. (I also had to chuckle at your optimism that the trickle/torrent was coming from me and not the people I talk to ... with me, it's only ever a trickle!).

Comment: I agree with Diego, a literal translation won't be good for this expression. "Término medio" is used often in a lot of scenarios, like yours.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the phrase **todo o nada**. It is not a literal translation, means "all or nothing", but is a common idiom that can be interpreted as "never average, always extreme". Your example would say so

> Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle, siempre es "todo o nada".

Answer (score 2):

I personally think the best compromise without it being too complicated would be:

> Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle hablo o muy poco o un montón.

Notice the form ***o xxx o yyy***, this is to denote two options, one of them always happens. If we simply say *siempre es poco o mucho* it isn't as clear and leaves some room to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

`Trickle` podría entenderse como `poca cantidad`, y `torrent` como `abundancia`.

Tu frase quedaría en español nativo:

> Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle, siempre es poco o mucho.

Para enfatizar podrías decir:

> Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle, siempre es muy poco o muchísimo.

No es correcto decir

> Muy mucho

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer could be:

> Cuando hablo español con la gente en la calle, siempre es muy poco o bastante.

Comment: Es una posible traducción, pero no utiliza ningún modismo o expresión para "muy poco o bastante", que creo que es lo que @badroit está tratando de encontrar.

Comment: Un modismo creo que no hay, porque según entiendo el gotero o lo torrente se podría entender como poco o bastante, dependería del punto de vista del lector la idea o sentido que le dá a la oración.

Comment: No pienso que es una muy buena traducción la verdad, no plasma el sentido que se quiere entregar.